# Why does nonclustered index column still do index scan instead of index seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have the following tables

**EmployeePatientLink**

```
Id nvarchar(128) PK & clustered index
PatientId nvarchar(128) FK NULL -- nonclustered index created
EmployeeId int NULL-- nonclustered index created.
```

**Patient**

```
Id nvarchar(128) PK & clustered index
Id PK & clustered Index  -- this links to above table
```

**PatientSchedule**

PatientId nvarchar(128) NULL   -- nonclustered index created

and this query

```
select 
    Id, PatientId 
from 
    PatientSchedule ps
Inner join 
    EmployeePatientLink ep on ps.PatientId = ep.PatientId
    where ep.EmployeeId=1111
```

I do have have similar queries like above and others perform index seek in the execution plan and Nested Loop joins.

However this one always includes Merge Join and Sort and Index scan.

I guess I have sufficient indexes created and everything is in order and it should be doing index seek.

Is there a specific reason why query optimizer chooses index seek?

Comment: Yes, there is a specific reason.  According to the statistics and rules built into the SQL Server optimizer, it determines that the index seek is the least expensive way to run the query.  You can add a hint to avoid merge joins and see what the cost would be in that case.

Comment: The SQL Server query optimizer might have determined that it's **cheaper** to do an index scan, rather than an index seek. This might be because the lack of a `WHERE` clause - if your query needs to return **every single entry** from that join, it might just be easier to **scan** the index. This is likely to change if you select only a single or a handful (few) entries with a good `WHERE` clause ....

Comment: Wow, `nvarchar(128)` clustered index key? ouch.There isn't a better option? You might give this a look: [How much does that key cost? (plus sp_helpindex9) - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/how-much-does-that-key-cost-plus-sp_helpindex9/) -- I don't think I could bring myself to try and query tune specific queries until I had a better clustering key.

Comment: @marc_s I do have where clause in the query but it's selecting on the employeepatientlink table . I did not add it in question

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do I do that ?

Comment: An index hint sounds like a bad idea, as the correct way to approach this would be to have the indexes created properly in a way which makes it intuitive for the optimizer to select it on its own. Perhaps if you posted the entire query (including the where clause) it would be plainly obvious why your index isn't being "seek"ed upon. From you script it seems as if the NC indexes are on a single column; that being said, if you have another column in the where clause which isn't in the NC index, it is effectively useless for the query in question.

Comment: @Eli edited the question to add where clause and column in EmployeePatient Link

Comment: Can you please put aliases on the selected columns in the query (patientid is found in both tables)? in the EmployeePatientLink table, are the patientid and the employeeid in the same NC index?

Comment: Could you show complete tables definition, including indexes (SSMS generated create script for example) and .sqlplan? How big is each table on your test server?

Answer (score 0):

Try create index with included columns to avoid "key lookup" (SQL Server need search for PatientId value when EmployeeId is found)

```
CREATE INDEX IX_EmployeePatientLink_EmployeeId ON EmployeePatientLink(EmployeeId) 
INCLUDE (PatientId)
```